# PostgreSQL reuse function call result

Tags: postgresql

I want to reuse an expensive function call in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT name,
  expensive_function(bar) as bars,
  array_length(bars) as total
FROM foos
GROUP BY name
```

but of course `bars` isn't a column so the following error is raised:

```
ERROR:  column "bars" does not exist
```

Is there a syntax or trick that will make this work?

Comment: Can you give some scope to reuse.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1296/

Comment: @JustKim Reuse meaning run the function once per row and use the resultant value for multiple return columns on that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common table expression (CTE) would work:

```
WITH subqry AS
  ( SELECT expensive_function(bar) AS bars
    FROM   foos )
SELECT bars,
       array_length(bars)
FROM   subqry;
```